# How to go back to the current state of the app after closing the app/app crashes using Ionic in iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

**Intro:**

In iOS native notes app (apple app), it's able to go back to the last view controller after closing the app completely. Surprisingly, even the things I've typed is still there after closing and reopening the app without me saving it.

[image]

**Question:**

I would like to achieve this in Ionic hybrid app in iOS. Could you please point me to the right direction and whether this is achievable?

I'm guessing the notes app is saving it into a file every time the user type a character. Isn't this a little too heavy for the app to handle?

**Problem:**

I'm building an app with many of forms fields to fill in (e.g. name, address, phone number...), I have a save button to store it into local storage. However, once the app crashes/close abruptly, I'll lose everything that I've typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with $watchGroup and watch all variables that you want to save, when you type you save that value to local Storage
I recommend that library for that https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Hey @Fabian Carrasco, thx for replying. By the way, what's the complications of saving everytime we type? Will it affect the performance when typing?

Comment: Hi :) In android I recommend to use CrossWalk to avoid loose performance.
Simply  ionic crosswalk add@12.41.296.5

Comment: Sorry  ionic browser add crosswalk 12.41.296.5